# connection to Informix still active despite closing?

Tags: informix

I have a small C# utility connecting (via the  IBM Data Server Provider for .NET) to a Informix DBS (version 11.7) and sending one or two queries to several databases. Even though I close each connection after the query is done, a call to `onstat -u` still lists my computer, with the flags Y and P (Waiting on a condition, Preparing/prepared, respectively) being set, one line for each query:

```
address          flags   sessid   user     tty      wait         tout locks nreads   nwrites
56413170         Y--P--- 704      user      MYWS  59dce6e8         0    1     64       0
```

The connections disappear when I end the program, or after a few minutes. I would expect my client not to show up immediately after closing the connection.

Is this a normal occurrence, or a sign that I might be doing something incorrectly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your connection pooling (settings in IBM Data Server Provider).
I never used it, but the docs on IBM Data provider say:

> **When a connection is first opened against a database, a connection pool is created. As connections are closed, they enter the pool, ready to be reused within the same process by other applications that need connections.**

So even if you close the "session" from you app to Informix DB, a connection is still active between IBM Server Provider and the Informix instance.

Hope this helps.

Comment: That was it, thanks for doing the research for me ;)

Comment: Glad I could help, you lazy one :)